# use of unassigned variable for local variable 'a'

Tags: c#

I use of unassigned variable for local variable 'a'

```
namespace ConsoleApplication36
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            float Salary, a;
            Salary= 300;

            if (Salary <= 100)
            a = Salary * 0; // a = amount paid
            Console.WriteLine("He Pays " + a);

            if (Salary <= 200)
            a = Salary * 5 / 100;
            Console.WriteLine("He Pays " + a);

            if (Salary <= 500)
            a = Salary * 10 / 100;
            Console.WriteLine("He Pays " + a);

            if (Salary > 500)
            a= Salary*15/100;
            Console.WriteLine("He Pays " + a);
            Console.In.ReadLine();

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: just write float Salary, a = 0; in declaration

Comment: This is because `a` is only assigned in an `if` statement.  While we can see that there is always an `if` statement entered in this case, sometimes this is not the case, so the compiler is actually helping is debug our code in more complex situations.  As Milos said, you should assign `a` to `0` when it is declared.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to assign `a` variable before using it. Change this line

```
float Salary, a;
```

to this

```
float Salary, a = 0;
```

Below is the complete modified code

```
namespace ConsoleApplication36
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            float Salary, a = 0;
            Salary= 300;
            if (Salary <= 100)
                a = Salary * 0; // a = amount paid

            Console.WriteLine("He Pays " + a);

            if (Salary <= 200)
                a = Salary * 5 / 100;
            Console.WriteLine("He Pays " + a);

            if (Salary <= 500)
                a = Salary * 10 / 100;
            Console.WriteLine("He Pays " + a);

            if (Salary > 500)
                a = Salary*15/100;
            Console.WriteLine("He Pays " + a);
            Console.In.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/YeljrN

Answer (score 2):

With your current syntax you would overwrite your a variable several times depending on the value of salary. Are you sure that's what you want? If not, make sure that you do the alternative calculation is in an else clause:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication36
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        float Salary = 300;
        float a = 0;

        if (Salary <= 100)
        {
            a = Salary * 0; // a = amount paid
        }
        else if (Salary <= 200)
        {
            a = Salary * 5 / 100;
        }
        else if (Salary <= 500)
        {
            a = Salary * 10 / 100;
        }
        else
        {
            a = Salary*15/100;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("He Pays " + a);
        Console.In.ReadLine();

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Set the initial value of a equal 0

```
namespace ConsoleApplication36
{ 
    class Program { 
    static void Main(string[] args) { 
    float Salary, a = 0; Salary= 300; if (Salary <= 100)

                    a = Salary * 0; // a = amount paid

                Console.WriteLine("He Pays " + a);

                if (Salary <= 200)
                    a = Salary * 5 / 100;
                Console.WriteLine("He Pays " + a);

                if (Salary <= 500)
                    a = Salary * 10 / 100;
                Console.WriteLine("He Pays " + a);

                    if (Salary > 500)
                        a= Salary*15/100;
                    Console.WriteLine("He Pays " + a);
                    Console.In.ReadLine();


            }
        }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Its better to declare them separately as you are new to C#

float salary;
float a=0;

The error is because CLR  is smart enough to check the path the code takes before reaching a particular use of a local variable and if you can get there with out assigning a value it will complain.